# Why a result of curl command in my pipilne script returns a missing value

Tags: curl, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am using CA Service Virtualization which allows to create a virtual service from a Swagger file with a specific POST request. I am trying to do a similar post request from jenkins pipeline however when I run my build I get an error that says that the values are missing.

The working curl command is:

```
curl -X POST "http://localhost:1505/lisa-virtualize-invoke/api/v3/vses/VSE/services" -H  "accept: application/json" -H  "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "config={"virtualService":{"version":"2","name":"API_Test_22","description":"Invoke API V2","status":""},"transportProtocol":{"typeId":"HTTP","basePath":"/","useGateway":true,"hostHeaderPassThrough":false},"dataProtocol":{"forRequest":true,"typeId":"RESTDPH"}}" -F "deploy=true" -F "inputFile1=@petstore-swagger.json;type=application/json"
```

I have been battling for a long time to make the curl command work in jenkins pipeline. I have had a lot of issues with

```
 "
```

characters. After many attempts my builds appears to be succesfull now but the values are missing and the virtual service is not created. I feel quite hopeless and I have no idea how to solve it. (below instead of a local Swagger file I am using GitHub one):

```
pipeline {
agent { label 'master' }
stages {
    stage('build') {
        steps {
            sh """curl -X POST -H \"authorization: Basic xxx" ""http://10.0.2.2:1505/lisa-virtualize-invoke/api/v3/vses/VSE/services"" -H \"accept: application/json\" -H \"Content-Type: multipart/form-data\" -F ""config={\"virtualService\":{\"version\":\"2\",\"name\":\"API_Test_22\",\"description\":\"Invoke API V2\",\"status\":\"\"},\"transportProtocol\":{\"typeId\":\"HTTP\",\"basePath\":\"/\",\"useGateway\":true,\"hostHeaderPassThrough\":false},\"dataProtocol\":{\"forRequest\":true,\"typeId\":\"RESTDPH\"}}"" -F \"deploy=true\" -F \"fileInput1=https://github.com/marcin-kulik/devttest-test/blob/master/petstore-swagger.json\""""
        }
    }
}
```

}

the output from jenkins is:

```
Started by user Marcin Kulik
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test-bash-in-pipeline
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (build)
[Pipeline] sh
+ curl -X POST -H authorization: Basic bWt1bGlrOm1qc2tleURCQ0g3MzUlXiY=    http://10.0.2.2:1505/lisa-virtualize-invoke/api/v3/vses/VSE/services -H accept: application/json -H Content-Type: multipart/form-data -F config={virtualService:{version:2,name:API_Test_22,description:Invoke API V2,status:},transportProtocol:{typeId:HTTP,basePath:/,useGateway:true,hostHeaderPassThrough:false},dataProtocol:{forRequest:true,typeId:RESTDPH}} -F deploy=true -F fileInput1=https://github.com/marcin-kulik/devttest-test/blob/master/petstore-swagger.json
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

 0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100   923    0   293  100   630    559   1202 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1761
{"error":{"type":"JSONException","message":"Missing value. at character 77 of {virtualService:{version:2,name:API_Test_22,description:Invoke API V2,status:},transportProtocol:{typeId:HTTP,basePath:/,useGateway:true,hostHeaderPassThrough:false},dataProtocol:{forRequest:true,typeId:RESTDPH}}"}}[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: Would super recommend setting up the body as a map and then converting it to JSON natively in Groovy.

Comment: please could you explain a bit more as I am not sure I understand thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For double quotes issues, try mixing with simple quotes, it can ease things.

```
pipeline {
    agent { label 'master' }
    stages {
        stage('build') {
            steps {
                sh 'curl -X POST -H "authorization: Basic xxx" "http://0.0.0.0/lisa-virtualize-invoke/api/v3/vses/VSE/services" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F \'config={"virtualService":{"version":"2","name":"API_Test_22","description":"Invoke API V2","status":""},"transportProtocol":{"typeId":"HTTP","basePath":"/","useGateway":true,"hostHeaderPassThrough":false},"dataProtocol":{"forRequest":true,"typeId":"RESTDPH"}}\' -F "deploy=true" -F "fileInput1=https://github.com/marcin-kulik/devttest-test/blob/master/petstore-swagger.json"'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Anyway, for your error, it looks like empty value for status field is not allowed.

Comment: Yes, this was a problem with quotes and parsing Json in Groovy

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the empty "status" value is not accepted.

You need to remove this key.

Comment: similar output after removing status key:

Comment: {"error":{"type":"JSONException","message":"Missing value. at character 111 of {virtualService:{version:2,name:API_Test_22,description:Invoke API V2},transportProtocol:{typeId:HTTP,basePath:/,useGateway:true,hostHeaderPassThrough:false},dataProtocol:{forRequest:true,typeId:RESTDPH}}"}}[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS